# Add Marker Annotations for Seaborn regplot

Tags: pandas, seaborn

This is my first question on the site, however I've spent a lot of time finding valuable answers here!

I've searched all over the site, and can't find a good solution to my problem, hopefully someone can help! I have a pandas database that I've created a regplot, however I'd really like to add annotations for each marker based on another column.
Here is the code for my existing plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8,5)
sns.regplot(x=brakev["Curb_Weight"], y=brakev["Braking_60_0"])
sns.regplot(x=brakev["Curb_Weight"], y=brakev["Braking_60_0"], fit_reg=False)
```

Here is the diagram: [regplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgJYj.png) 
. I found a proposal on the Python Graph Gallery (and others on Stack Overflow), but I'm struggling to get it to work:

```
for line in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    p1.text(df.x[line]+0.2, df.y[line], df.group[line], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

I'd like to add an annotation from the column 'Model' next to each marker. I'm less concerned about the position, color, font size at the moment, but that would also be helpful.

Here is the brakev.head() for my database:

```
brakev.head()
    Model           Curb_Weight Braking_60_0
0   Transit Connect 3580.0      132.0
1   NV200           3690.0      129.0
2   Sprinter        3710.0      132.0
3   Express         3620.0      135.0
4   Transit         3960.0      136.0
```

Sorry if this is a duplication, (I'm sure it is, but I can't find it!!). Thanks for the help!

Comment: This being your first question you'd want to read [ask] and [mcve]. What is especially important is that the code is clear and runnable and that you explain the desired and undesired outcome. "struggling to get it to work" is not a useful problem description. Are you getting an error? if so show the traceback. Does the plot look unexpected, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution! The key was to first store each of the x, y, and label elements into a list:

```
Curb_Weight = brakev.Curb_Weight.tolist()
Braking_60_0 = brakev.Braking_60_0.tolist()
Model = brakev.Model.tolist()
```

After this, the proposed solution was relatively easy to implement:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(20,12)
sns.regplot(data=brakev, x='Curb_Weight', y='Braking_60_0')
p1 = sns.regplot(data=brakev, x='Curb_Weight', y='Braking_60_0',fit_reg=False,marker='o',scatter_kws={'s':50})

for line in range(0,brakev.shape[0]):
    p1.text(Curb_Weight[line]+1.8, Braking_60_0[line], Model[line],
            horizontalalignment='left',size='medium',color='black',weight='semibold')
```

The result includes the annotation label next to the markers, and is relatively legible excluding a few overlaps:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fv8L.png)

If anyone has suggestions for optimization, or ideas how to "flip" the orientation of the label when another marker is within a specific range to avoid the overlap, let me know!